# ActiveAdmin and Dynamic Rails namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activeadmin

The administrative panel manages employees of organizations. Now each organization has its own subdomain:

```
dms.site.com/admin
fake.site.com/admin
```

But I want to use rails namespaces without subdomains:

```
scope '/*business' do
  devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

And routes:

```
site.com/dms/admin
site.com/fake/admin
```

But ActiveAdmin does not understand how it should build links. For the menu I did so (and it works):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_default_url_options

  ...
  def set_default_url_options
    Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:business] = current_business.scope
  end
  ...

end

# => site.com/dms/admin/employees
# => site.com/fake/admin/employees
```

But I can not teach him how to build links for resource actions correctly:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Employee do

  ...
  index do
    column :name
    actions defaults: true do |manager|
      # reset password - ok, but actions for new, edit etc. - no =(
      link_to 'Reset password', reset_password_admin_employee_path(manager, business: 'dms'), method: :post
    end
  end
  ...

end
```

I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :business=>#<Employee id: 12, email: "jaydon.jones@example.org", name: "Deontae Rowe", role: "employee", position_id: 1, business_id: 1, super_administrator: false, created_at: "2018-08-11 09:18:57", updated_at: "2018-08-11 09:18:57">, :controller=>"admin/employees"}, missing required keys: [:id]):
1: insert_tag renderer_for(:index)

app/admin/users/employees.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```